# Python Regex to Split a line into 4 parts

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How can I use regex to split each line the following

```
3 Name Test 50.5 -
2 Name-Test - 3.12
1 Name Test Test 50.5 -
2 Name Test 32 213.12
3 Name Test 50.5 -
2 Name Test - 50.12
1 Name Test 50.5 -
2 Name Test - -
```

Would be split into:

```
3 | Name Test | 50.5 | -
2 | Name-Test | - | 3.12
1 | Name Test Test | 50.5 | -
2 | Name Test | 32 | 213.12
3 | Name Test | 50.5 | -
2 | Name Test | - | 50.12
1 | Name Test | 50.5 | -
2 | Name Test | - | -
```

The furthest I got was: `re.compile('(\d+) (.+) (\w+.\w+)')`

Wherever the `|` symbols are is where the splits need to be...

Comment: This is matching, not splitting (splitting would be `re.split`).

Comment: Can your `Name Test` part contain digit? Something like - `Name - Test 23 Test`?

Comment: The `Name Test` part can contain numbers yes It could be anything like `Test22Test` or `Test 22 Test` or `Test 22-Test` or `Test-22-Test` all versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `^(\d+) (.+) (\d+\.\d+|-|\d+) (\d+\.\d+|-|\d+)$`

This should match all of your example strings.

All the best SMNALLY

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here's another way. This is based on "splitting" for your specific use case and does not involve regular expressions. The key idea is that the second column (name) can have spaces in it, while all other columns have a well-defined format. So the idea is to split from the right and left, leaving the remainder (the name column) intact:

```
def mysplit(line):
    r = line.rsplit(' ', 2)
    l = r[0].split(' ', 1)
    print " | ".join(l + r[i:])
```

When I run the following snippet in IPython with your input in `/tmp/lines.txt`:

```
for l in open('/tmp/lines.txt'):
    mysplit(l.strip())
```

Results in:

```
3 | Name Test | 50.5 | -
2 | Name-Test | - | 3.12
1 | Name Test Test | 50.5 | -
2 | Name Test | 32 | 213.12
3 | Name Test | 50.5 | -
2 | Name Test | - | 50.12
1 | Name Test | 50.5 | -
2 | Name Test | - | -
```

Comment: I thought of this approach (and would tend to prefer it) but was too lazy to do it. I think, however, that he's trying to get a tuple out of it; the `|` separation was just indicative of the split points.

Answer (score 2):

A potentially appropriate regular expression to match on would be:

```
^(\d+) (.+) (\d+(\.\d+)?|-) (\d+(\.\d+)?|-)$
```

Example usage:

```
>>> re.match(r'(\d+) (.+) (\d+(\.\d+)?|-) (\d+(\.\d+)?|-)$', '3 Name Test 50.5 -').groups()
('3', 'Name Test', '50.5', '-')
```

Comment: I tried: `re.compile('(\d+) (.+) (.+) (.+)` what are the downsides of this?

Comment: @Hyflex: if you're not sure about that, you're probably not ready to use regular expressions yet. I suggest you read up about them; it'll really pay off.

Comment: I've read into them just don't 100% understand them, I'm still learning.